# Helper function to convert integer to string to integer in fibonacci with memoization

Tags: types, ocaml

I am trying to write a function to utilize memoization in a recursive fibonacci function and have the output returned as a string.

My current code is as follows:

```
let cache = Hashtbl.create 100;;
Hashtbl.add cache 0 0;;
Hashtbl.add cache 1 1;;
let rec f(n:int): string =
    match Hashtbl.mem cache n with
    | true -> Hashtbl.find cache n
    | false ->
        let result = (f (n - 1)) + (f (n - 2)) in
        Hashtbl.add cache n result;
        result
;;
```

I was hoping to use this method and use `string_of_int` at the end to convert result to a string, but am being blocked by this error in line 6: (`| true -> Hashtbl.find cache n`):

```
This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type string.
```

I am assuming that I need a helper function to convert the integer to string but don't understand how the later arithmetic can be done with strings.

I tried converting the int to string before `| true -> hashtbl.find cache n`, and was expecting for the table to take in my values.

Comment: It expects a string because you say it should be a string. It compiles fine if you remove that annotation, and it's not clear why it should return a string. Why not just remove it?

Comment: The comment of @glennsl is especially true as you are doing a recursive call and trying to add the result, which only makes sense if it returns an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, your problem comes entirely from unnecessarily typing the result of f as `string`, since `Hashtbl.find cache n` must return an `int`.

```
let cache = Hashtbl.create 100;;
Hashtbl.add cache 0 0;;
Hashtbl.add cache 1 1;;
let rec f (n:int) =
  match Hashtbl.mem cache n with
  | true -> Hashtbl.find cache n
  | false ->
    let result = f (n - 1) + f (n - 2) in
    Hashtbl.add cache n result;
    result
```

Should you wish to return a string, you need to convert the return value and then convert back on each recursive call. But it seems a bit silly to do this much work.

```
let rec f(n:int): string =
  match Hashtbl.mem cache n with
  | true -> string_of_int @@ Hashtbl.find cache n 
  | false ->
    let result = int_of_string (f (n - 1)) + int_of_string (f (n - 2)) in
    Hashtbl.add cache n result;
    string_of_int result
```

Instead if you really need the result as a string, simply convert that value to a string.

```
utop # string_of_int @@ f 20;;
- : string = "6765"
```

Hashtables certainly have their uses, but OCaml is a functional programming language, so surely we can find a solution sans mutable state with the `Map` module rather than `Hashtbl`.

The first step is to create an appropriate map module. Easier done than said.

```
module Int_map = Map.Make(Int)
```

Now the trick with using `Int_map` rather than a hash table, is that to benefit from building the map, we have to keep passing it around, which means `fib` has to return not only the result, but also a resulting map.

```
let rec fib n ?(cache=Int_map.(empty |> add 0 0 |> add 1 1)) () =
  Int_map.(
    match find n cache with   
    | v -> (v, cache)
    | exception Not_found -> 
      let (result',  cache) = fib (n-1) ~cache () in  
      let (result'', cache) = fib (n-2) ~cache () in  
      let result = result' + result'' in
      (result, add n result cache)
  )
```

```
utop # fib 20 ();;
- : int * int Int_map.t = (6765, <abstr>)
```

Fortunately if we no longer need the map, it's easy to select just the numeric result.

```
utop # fst @@ fib 20 ();;
- : int = 6765
```

If you want to *see* the map, it's easy to do so.

```
utop # fib 8 () |> snd |> Int_map.bindings;;
- : (int * int) list =
[(0, 0); (1, 1); (2, 1); (3, 2); (4, 3); (5, 5); (6, 8); (7, 13); (8, 21)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered previously. However, I want to note that we can implement the Fibonacci function in a more efficient way and without mutability using tail-recursion :

```ml
let fibo n =
  let rec aux n a b = if n = 0 then a else aux (n - 1) b (a + b) in
  aux n 0 1
```

This simple implementation is times faster than the previous `fib` function.
For example, `fib 100_000` takes 0.51 ms to calculate, but `fibo 100_000` takes only 0.0032 ms (160 times faster).